# A series with only rational terms for $\ln \ln 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, logarithms, real-numbers

We all know that

> $$
> \ln 2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}.
> $$

Do you know a series with only rational terms for

> $$\ln \ln 2 = ?$$

Let's exclude base expansions with non explicit coefficients.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "exclude explicit base expansions"?

Comment: @mweiss No. If you have a series with only rational terms which is a base expansion with explicit coefficients, we take it! Hoping to be clear.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such a rational series can certainly be written down, though I only consider this answer a partial result since I won't express it as a single sum. From the Taylor series $\ln(1+x)=-\sum_{j=1}^\infty (-x)^j/j$ we may write $\ln\ln(1+x)$ as
\begin{align}
 \ln\ln(1+x)
&= \ln\left(x-\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{(-x)^j}{j}\right)\\
&= \ln x + \ln\left(1+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{j-1}}{j}\right) \\
&= \ln x-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\left(-\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{j-1}}{j}\right)^k.
\end{align}
Note that the second term is certainly a rational series in powers of $x$, albeit not one which seems easy to express term-by-term; presumably one could expand using the binomial theorem and resum over $k$. The limit as $x\to 1$ then kills the first term and so yields
$$\ln\ln 2 = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(-\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}\right)^k.$$ Can anyone reduce this further? Note that this amounts to expressing the Taylor series of $\ln(\ln(1+x)/x)$ in a tractable way.

---

Update:

After some further work, I remembered that [Faa di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faa_di_Bruno's_formula) expresses the Taylor series of $h(x)=f(g(x))$ in terms of [Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomial) as $$h^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(g(x))\cdot B_{n,k}(g'(x),g''(x),\ldots,g^{(n-k+1)}(x).$$ We can use this to obtain the derivatives at $x=0$ in a rather mechanical way. For our purposes, we take $f(x)=\ln x$ and $g(x)=\ln(1+x)/x$. Then $f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^{k-1} (k-1)!\,x^{-k}$ and $g^{(k)}(0)=(-1)^k k!/(k+1),$ so

\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[\ln\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right)\right]_{x=0}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(1)\cdot B_{n,k}\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\ldots,(-1)^{n-k+1}\frac{(n-k+1)!}{n-k+2}\right) \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (k-1)!\,(-1)^{k-1} B_{n,k}\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\ldots,(-1)^{n-k+1}\frac{(n-k+1)!}{n-k+2}\right)
\end{align}
With this, we can express the Taylor series about $x=0$ for the function and take as above the limit as $x\to 1$:

\begin{align}
\ln\ln 2
&=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\ln\left[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\right]
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{h^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \frac{(k-1)!}{n!}\, B_{n,k}\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\ldots,(-1)^{n-k+1}\frac{(n-k+1)!}{n-k+2}\right).
\end{align}

This is still a pretty miserable looking expression, but this approach has gotten rid of the powers of $\ln(1+x)/x$ that were present above. Can anyone take this further?

Comment: between your first and second lines, it looks like you've factored $x$ from $(-x)^j$ to give $(-x)^{j-1}$ but wouldn't it give $(-1)^{j}x^{j-1}$?

Comment: @oliveeuler: Good point. I've fixed it.

Comment: in the third line, shouldn't the sum be $-\sum{\frac{\left(-\sum...\right)^k}{k}}$?

Comment: @Semiclassical The point is that $\left(-\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j-1}}{j}\right)^k$ is not rational, since $\ln 2$ is not an algebraic number.

Comment: @oliveeuler: Once again, correct and corrected.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: No, it's not. But you can expand that using the binomial theorem (well, really the multinomial theorem) and get a sum of rational terms. Or, to put it another way: $\ln\ln(1+x)-\ln x$ has a Taylor series with rational coefficients, and so $\ln\ln 2$ has a rational series as well.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I believe that was directed at me; I'm aware of his point and am certain that he is correct though I wanted to make sure that the argument is completely valid.

Comment: @semiclassical OK.

Comment: Come to think of it, if the Taylor series for $\ln(\ln(1+x)/x)$ is given somewhere then that'd give $\ln\ln 2$ more directly. Perhaps I'll go digging.

Comment: @Semiclassical I haven't so far found one without $\ln(x)$ nor $\zeta(x)$ so the search may not be too fruitful.

Comment: Your inner sum is conditionally convergent, so simplifying this into a single series is probably not viable. (Though you could couple this approach with some log identities to get around that...)

Comment: I think any approach with a Taylor series polynomial is doomed since the derivative of $\ln(\ln(1+x))$ is undefined at $x=1$.

Comment: @NovaDenizen: For $\ln\ln(1+x)$, yes. But as mentioned in an earlier comment, what really matters is $\ln(\ln(1+x)/x)=\ln\ln(1+x)-\ln x$ (the ill-definedness is due to that $\ln x$).

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks! Your update answer is very clear. I accept it! I doubt the final expression can be considerably simplified. I suggest another point of view.

Answer (score 6):

We have

> $$
> \ln \ln 2  =   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \! \left(\sum_{k = 1 }^{n } \frac{{n \brack k}}{k+1}\right)\frac{1}{n!} \tag1
> $$

where ${n \brack k}$ are the unsigned **Stirling numbers of the first kind** counting the numbers of permutations of
$n$ letters that have exactly $k$ cycles.

**Proof.**  Let $-1<t<1$. Recall the exponential generating function of the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind 
$$
\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \displaystyle  \frac{{n \brack k}}{n!} t^{n} = \displaystyle \frac{\left(-\ln(1-t)\right)^{k}}{k!}, \quad k=1,2 \cdots. \tag2
$$
[[Herbert S. Wilf, *generatingfunctionology*]](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)   p. 82 (3.5.3)

On one hand we have
$$
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left( \sum_{k = 1 }^{n } \frac{{n \brack k}}{k+1}\right) \frac{t^{n-1}}{n!} & =  \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{t} 
 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1} \sum_{n = k }^{\infty} \frac{{n \brack k}}{n!}(-t)^{n} \\
& =  \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{t} 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-\ln(1+t)\right)^{k}}{(k+1)!} \\
& =  \frac{1}{t} +
\displaystyle \frac{1}{-t\ln(1+t)}\left(e^{-\ln(1+t)} + \ln(1+t) - 1\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{(1+t) \ln(1+t)} ,
\end{align}
$$
that is
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left( \sum_{k = 1 }^{n } \frac{{n \brack k}}{k+1}\right) \frac{t^{n-1}}{n!} =   -\frac{1}{t}+ \frac{1}{(1+t) \ln(1+t)}. \tag3
$$

On the other hand we have

$$
\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt} \ln \left( \frac{\ln (1+t)}{t} \right)  =   -\frac{1}{t}+ \frac{1}{(1+t) \ln(1+t)}.  \tag4
$$

We deduce that

> $$
> \ln \left( \frac{\ln (1+t)}{t} \right)  =   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \left( \sum_{k = 1 }^{n } \frac{{n \brack k}}{k+1}\right) \frac{t^{n}}{n!}, \quad 0<t<1. \tag5
> $$

This gives, as $t$ tends to $1^-$, 
$$
\ln \ln 2  =   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \! \left(\sum_{k = 1 }^{n } \frac{{n \brack k}}{k+1}\right)\frac{1}{n!} .
$$
**Remark.** As $n$ tends to $\infty$, one may prove ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872042/an-asymptotic-term-for-a-finite-sum-involving-stirling-numbers)) that
$$
\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k = 1 }^{n } \frac{{n \brack k}}{k+1} \sim \frac{1}{\ln n}. \tag6
$$

Comment: Very nice! I imagine there's some way to directly verify the correspondence between our answers, i.e. some relevant Bell<->Stirling identity.

Comment: What would be _really_ nice would be to have an interpretation of $\ln(\ln(1+x)/x)$ as an (exponential?) generating function. Flajolet's _Analytic Combinatorics_ would be a place to look.

Comment: Check http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C7%2C35%2C228&sort=&language=english&go=Search for the EGF of $\ln(1/(1+\ln(1-x))$ - definitely involves Stirling numbers - probably close enough for your purposes.