# Simplify an iterated function

Tags: logarithms, function-and-relation-composition

If we iterate the function $f(x) = \ln(x + 1)$, we get:
$$f(f(x)) = f^2(x) = \ln(\ln(x + 1) + 1)$$
$$f(f(f(x))) = f^3(x) = \ln(\ln(\ln(x + 1) + 1) + 1)$$
$$f(f(f(f(x)))) = f^4(x) = \ln(\ln(\ln(\ln(x + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1)$$
And so forth. I was wondering if there is some clever way to deal with these forms of expressions to simplify them any more. Everything I tried failed (and spectacularly at that), so if there is some neat trick we could use to write the general iterate $f^n(x)$ in closed form.

Honestly, I don't expect any simplification to be possible, but I just wanted to be absolutely sure.

Comment: I dont think there is any simplification either

Comment: I do not know whether ther is, but the notation $f^n$ you used seems perfectly fine, since it is a widely used one. And I never came across a simplification (or it was a really special function).

Comment: I agree that there is no simple closed form.  I think there might be a reasonable expression for the $n^{th}$ iterate in terms of a power series, which is nice if you happen to be studying the iteration of $f$ in a neighborhood of the origin.

Comment: With regards to power series of the iterated log, this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/870070/137524) of mine may be of interest.  @MarkMcClure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [super-logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm) and the [iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) function could be interesting, but these are kind of "limits" for your $f^{(n)}$. I doubt if there is simplification for a given $n$.